# swagger-ui-express not displaying response

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

Chrome gets a 200 response with the expect data. But swagger is not displaying the result.

Swagger Options:

```
swaggerOptions = {
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  swaggerDefinition : {
    info: {
      title: 'Admin API',
      description: 'Admin API integration',
      version: "1.0",
      contact: {
        name: 'Vinicius A. Da Silva'
      },
      servers: [
        'http://localhost:3000'
      ]
    },
    produces: ["application/json"],
    securityDefinitions: {
      bearerAuth: {
        type: 'apiKey',
        name: 'Authorization',
        scheme: 'bearer',
        in: 'header',
        bearerFormat: 'JWT',
      },
    },
    security: [ { bearerAuth: [] } ],
  },
  apis: [__dirname+'/controller/*.js']
}
```

Jsdoc comment:

```
/**
     * @swagger
     *  /api/list?mdl={mdl}:
     *      security:
     *          - Bearer: []
     *      get:
     *          description: Returns all users
     *          responses:
     *          '200':
     *              description: Successfully returned paginated records
     *          '403':
     *              description: Not enough permissions read_modelName
     *      parameters:
     *          - name: mdl
     *            in: query
     *            description: Model name
     *            required: true
     *            schema:
     *              type: string
     *              format: string
     *      responses:
     *          '200':
     *              description: Successfully inserted a user
     *              content:
     *                  'application/json':
     *                      schema:
     *                          type: object
     *                          description: test response
     *          '403':
     *              description: Not enough permissions
     */
```

Image:

[image]

The response ui part of it, is not displaying.
Even though Chrome is getting 200 http response and the response data.

**SOLUTION:**

The responses property must be within the http related method.

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *  /api/list?mdl={mdl}:
 *      security:
 *          - Bearer: []
 *      get:
 *          description: Returns all users
 *          responses:
 *              '200':
 *                  description: Successfully returned paginated records
 *              '403':
 *                  description: Not enough permissions read_modelName
 *      parameters:
 *          - name: mdl
 *            in: query
 *            description: Model name
 *            required: true
 *            schema:
 *              type: string
 *              format: string
 */
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, change your `bearerAuth` definition to `type: http` + `scheme: bearer` (without other fields). This way when you authorize requests in Swagger UI, you can specify the bearer token without the "Bearer" prefix, the prefix will be added automatically.

Comment: @Helen when I do that, I get the following message when I click on the Authorize button: "Unknown security definition type http"

Answer (score 4):

That is happening because the format of your JSdoc comment is wrong. There should be a tab space in the next line after `responses` key that you declared first so it should be like this.

```
   /**
    * @swagger
    *  /api/list?mdl={mdl}:
    *      security:
    *          - Bearer: []
    *      get:
    *          description: Returns all users
    *          responses:
    *              '200':
    *                  description: Successfully returned paginated records
    *              '403':
    *                  description: Not enough permissions read_modelName
    *      parameters:
    *          - name: mdl
    *            in: query
    *            description: Model name
    *            required: true
    *            schema:
    *              type: string
    *              format: string
    *      responses:
    *          '200':
    *              description: Successfully inserted a user
    *              content:
    *                  'application/json':
    *                      schema:
    *                          type: object
    *                          description: test response
    *          '403':
    *              description: Not enough permissions
    */
```

Comment: @Hanza Anis Thank you.

Comment: It is ! Thanks a lot for your help.